# Cannot modify Audit Policy

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I would like to setup an audit policy on my servers but in each server I want setup I am not able to modify anything also in the domain controllers server I cannot set it up. In fact each time I open the Audit Policy to modify this window appears:

[image: Audit logon event properties]

> "This setting might not be enforced if other policy is configured to override category level audit policy."  This is happen on a Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2

Do you have any suggestion to work out this step?

Answer (score 1):

The setting is dimmed because it is configured using Group Policy. If a system has settings configured in Group Policy, that is where it needs to be changed.